# either inifinitive or gerund

Tags: usage

All government officials above the rank of undersecretary have been issued circulars by their respective ministries **to ask** them to attend yoga classes in the run up to the event.

I think **to ask** and **asking** both can be used.

Comment: The infinitive seems clumsy; the other (which I would call a *present participle* rather than a *gerund* since **asking** is not used as a noun) flows better.

Comment: is infinitive not grammatical?

Comment: No, it's not ungrammatical, but the grammar is different. The infinitival is a purpose adjunct while the gerund-participial is a modifier of "circulars".

Comment: @BillJ If I don't want to modify circulars then use of infinitive is justified?